# SharePoint Upgrade from 2007 to 2013 via DB attach method

Tags: 2007, upgrade, content-database, database-attach

I am currently in the process of migrating a sharepoint site from 2007 to 2013 via a double hop database attach method.

But i am attaching the content db to 2010 environment then it gives me the following error.

> [Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence] cannot
>   upgrade an object [SPContentDatabase Name=test_ContentDB_BackUp]
>   whose build version [12.0.0.6318] is too old . Upgrade requires
>   [12.0.0.6421] or higher.

Pls suggest what is the right 2010 version to make it work. because i can not make any changes to the 2007 version and i have configured the 2010 as test environment so i can either upgrade or make changes.

Comment: what is sharepoint 2007 version?

Comment: also did you run the preupgrade checker in 2007 farm STSADM.EXE -o preupgradecheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your environment must be updated to at least Service Pack 2 of Office SharePoint Server 2007 to run the upgrade process, either for an in-place or database attach upgrade. We recommend that you install the October 2009 Cumulative Update because it includes improvements to the pre-upgrade checker tool.

[Review system requirements for upgrade (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263322.aspx)

You are  `12.0.0.6318( MOSS 2007 – WSS 3.0 Infrastructure Update)`, you need to update the `services pack 2(12.0.0.6421)`

Comment: can i consider migrating to sharepoint server 2010 with no service packs. will it work ? or is it mandatory to have SP2 in 2007 environment

Comment: Sp2 is min req, must have

Comment: i have another sp 2007 with sp2 farm, can i just add this db to one of the sitecollection and dettach so i can reuse in 2010 upgrade. pls let me know.

Comment: If you have another farm with SP2 then you can detach the current db from non-sp2 farm, make a backup and restore on SP2 farm...attach to SP2 farm web app...now it will upgraded to new version...now detach from SP2 farm and move to sp2010 farm.