# SharePoint 2010 content DB attach

Tags: 2010, content-database, database-attach, space-usage

I am attaching a content db from moss 2007 SP version to SharePoint enterprise 2010 edition as part of [refer for the overall objective](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145206/sharepoint-upgrade-from-2007-to-2013-via-db-attach-method). but the content db is occupying the complete space. is there any best practice or configurations that should be followed.

Comment: what you mean by occupy the space...how much space you have in 2007 and how much you see the space after move.

Comment: say if i have 150 GB content database with free space on drive is 300gb. it is giving an error saying " Action 4.0.98.0 of Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPContentDatabaseSequence failed to rollback" with all the 300gb space occupied.

Comment: Data drive on SQL server is same as System Drive? how much space u have on C drive(system)

Comment: i have 300gb of total space in which OS and other files occupies 50GB - both in same c drive.

Comment: In this scentio, I would try to remove the unwanted stuff from site collection, shrink the db...reduce the size so that it can be upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is expected behavior.

When performing the upgrade, you need to plan on having plenty of drive space available on both **System drive** as well as **Data drive** and **Log Drive for SQL**.
Here is some real time example.

> Once I moved the database to a terrabyte partition, the error was
> resolved. I found that, in order to reliably upgrade a SharePoint 2007
> content databases to 2010, you'll need to plan for allowing the
> content database to triple in size during the upgrade. If your content
> database is 100 GB, you'll need at least 300 GB for the log files to
> grow.
> [SharePoint 2010 Upgrade Failure - Executing DDL Script](http://practicalsharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/08/sharepoint-2010-upgrade-failure.html)
> When we migrated our 2007 to 2010, I checked, we had 3 times of the existing size of DB.

http://blog.armgasys.com/?p=108

Comment: i have increased the space to 3 times and i will post my comments on the outcome.